# Generated Access Token invalid for Demo Video Application

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am using the sample Video application pulled from GitHub. I am using a node.js server to supply the sample application with the access token. When I use the Twilio Console to generate a video access token and put it in my Node.js server as a literal and return it I am able to run the example application and connect to a room. If I use the sample token generation code in my Node.js server I get 'Invalid Access Token' back in an exception in the onDisconnected method in the Room.Listener.

The following code is what is running in the server to create the access token, I also found a different sample which I tried as well. I have gone back and verified that my data values for the account SID and the API keys are correct. I have a similar method running returning the VoiceGrant access token and that is working, but something about this VideoGrant one is off, I just do not see it.

```
// ***********************************************************************************
// ***********************************************************************************
// Video Access Token
// ***********************************************************************************
// ***********************************************************************************
var videoCallAccessToken = function(request, response) {
        console.log('/twilio/video/accessToken');
        var accessToken = makeVideoAccessToken();
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        response.end(accessToken);
        console.log(accessToken);
};

app.get('/twilio/video/accessToken', videoCallAccessToken);

var makeVideoAccessToken = function() {
        const AccessToken = twilio.AccessToken;
        const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;
        const grant = new VideoGrant({configurationProfileSid: accountData.videoConfigurationProfileSid});
        const accessToken = new AccessToken(accountData.sid, accountData.videoApiSid, accountData.videoApiSecret);
        accessToken.identity = 'ABC123';
        accessToken.addGrant(grant);
        return accessToken.toJwt();
};
```

FYI...I plan to alter the identity generation, but have not got there yet.

Thanks,

Comment: Ok, thought I had waited long enough prior to actually sending this, but apparently not. The issue is the example does not work in that the value passed into the VideoGrant constructor needed to have the attribute name quoted, so {configurationProfileSid: accountData.videoConfigurationProfileSid}); needed to be {'configurationProfileSid': accountData.videoConfigurationProfileSid}); Glad I finally found that, wasted a ton of time on it, but at least it is working properly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this from my comment as an answer to close this question out, the issue was that the example code was flawed...

Ok, thought I had waited long enough prior to actually sending this, but apparently not. The issue is the example does not work in that the value passed into the VideoGrant constructor needed to have the attribute name quoted, so {configurationProfileSid: accountData.videoConfigurationProfileSid}); needed to be {'configurationProfileSid': accountData.videoConfigurationProfileSid}); Glad I finally found that, wasted a ton of time on it, but at least it is working properly now.